# I’m trying to find a book about portals to other dimensions

Tags: story-identification, books

I am trying to find a book I read a couple years ago, where the main character is a kid whose parents disappear. Some people who are the family’s friends come there, and the kid finds out that his parents are guardians to portals that lead to other dimensions and they have an entire lab of sorts under their house. Basically the story follows him trying to find out where they disappeared and becomes the new guardian. The parents like went into one of the portals and now can’t come back for a few years. Please help me find this book.

Comment: Steven Gould's "Wildside" hits a lot of your marks.  Not posting it as an answer because I haven't read it in a long time.  But if it's not the one, maybe you'd like that one too.  https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/1006354.Wildside

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Googling suggests there are quite a few books along these lines. One that seems to fit your description pretty well is [The Portal](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1714672.The_Portal) by Andrew Norriss, published in 2007:

[image: The Portal]

> You tend to remember the day your parents disappear. It's one of those things that sticks in your mind. Another of those things is the incredible discovery that behind your dad's office door lies an intergalactic portal . . .
>
> When both of these things happen to William Seward and his brother Daniel they're left with two questions. What are they going to do now? And where are their parents?

The main protagonist is *William*. When he finds his parents have disappeared he rings an emergency number left for him by his father and *Uncle Larry* turns up. Uncle Larry first tries to convince William that his parents have gone on holiday in France, but when this doesn't work he gives in and takes the boys down a secret elevator to his father's underground lab where the portal is.

> In the centre of the room was what looked like a pool, set into the middle of the floor. It was circular, about two metres in diameter and the lip, made of the same material as the walls and floor, was about fifteen centimetres high. Inside, there was a milky liquid that rippled and swirled, though the more he looked at it, the more William wondered if it was really a liquid at all, and then he found that staring at it made him slightly seasick.
>
> "That's where your parents went." Uncle Larry pointed at the pool. "At least I think it is."
>
> "What ... what is it?" asked William.
>
> "It’s a Portal," said Uncle Larry. "A Star Portal."

It turns out that:

> Williams mother had fallen and been seriously injured while collecting plants, and his father had taken her through a portal to get help. However because the main portal was down for maintenance he had to use a backup called the *Old Portal* that works but takes three and a half years to transfer travellers through it. At the end of the book William has been put in charge of the portal and has to wait the three and a half years for his parents to appear at the other end.

A neat trick for finding books is to search the Goodreads site by appending `site:goodreads.com/book/` to the search. In this case I searched for [`parents disappear portal site:goodreads.com/book/`](https://www.google.com/search?q=parents%20disappear%20portal%20site%3Agoodreads.com%2Fbook%2F) and *The Portal* was top of the list.

Comment: Oh my god this is it, thanks so much